# How to combine data arrays by multi longitude and latitude in one dataset in python

Tags: python, data-structures, dataset, python-xarray

I made for loop of my data array of each long/lat point and I appended all result in one list as below :

```
out_list=[]
for i in ds.longitude.values:
    for j in ds.latitude.values:
        point = arr.sel(longitude=i,latitude=j)
        
        p_detrend = sm.tsa.tsatools.detrend(point, order=1,axis=0)
        out_list.append(p_detrend)
```

and my list as below :
[image]
and you can see there are many arrays and each one has long/lat . How to combine all arrays in one dataset by longitude and latitude ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you use `xarray.merge()`?

I used the example from [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html) and your description to create a fake data for different longitudes and latitudes, all stacked in a list.

Then, if I use `xarray.merge()`, it will automatically structure the data into `('time','longitude','latitude')` xarray object.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(123)

xr.set_options(display_style="html")

times = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2001-12-31", name="time")
annual_cycle = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (times.dayofyear.values / 365.25 - 0.28))

ds = []

for lon in range(-40,-30):
    for lat in range(0,10):
        base = 10 + 15 * annual_cycle.reshape(-1,1,1)
        tmin = base + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size,1,1)
        tmax = base + 10 + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size,1,1)

        ds.append(xr.Dataset(
            {
                "tmin": (("time", "latitude","longitude"), tmin),
                "tmax": (("time", "latitude","longitude"), tmax),
            },
            {"time": times,"latitude":[lat],"longitude":[lon]},
        ))
ds = xr.merge(ds)
```

First, `ds` will be like a list of different `xarray` objects for each latitude and longitude:

```
[<xarray.Dataset>
 Dimensions:    (latitude: 1, longitude: 1, time: 731)
 Coordinates:
   * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2001-12-31
   * latitude   (latitude) int64 0
   * longitude  (longitude) int64 -40
 Data variables:
     tmin       (time, latitude, longitude) float64 -4.646 -3.527 ... -3.939
     tmax       (time, latitude, longitude) float64 8.436 1.992 ... 3.366 1.605,
 <xarray.Dataset>
 Dimensions:    (latitude: 1, longitude: 1, time: 731)
 Coordinates:
   * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2001-12-31
   * latitude   (latitude) int64 1
   * longitude  (longitude) int64 -40
 Data variables:
     tmin       (time, latitude, longitude) float64 -2.966 -3.322 ... -7.731
     tmax       (time, latitude, longitude) float64 3.156 5.467 ... 11.85 7.26,
 <xarray.Dataset>
.
.
.
.
]
```

Then, after the merge, it will be a `xarray.dataset` just like this:

[image: repr]

Please, let me know if that helps, or if I need to adapt in some way to work for your specific type of data.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use dictionary instead, something like:

```
out_list = []

for i in ds.longitude.values:
    for j in ds.latitude.values:
        point = arr.sel(longitude=i,latitude=j)
        p_detrend = sm.tsa.tsatools.detrend(point, order=1,axis=0)

        result = {
            'longitude': i, 
            'latitude': j,
            'detrend_arr': p_detrend  
        }
        out_list.append(result)
```

then you may use pandas to convert into `pd.DataFrame` for other manipulation;